# VS2022 Clickonce restores Application Folders

Tags: clickonce, visual-studio-2022

Im using click once to publish a simple application that uses EF and WPF.

I noticed in the application folders directory that it publishes too it will replace missing incremental of the application.  I even trying creating a new .pubxml instance but that still restores the old folders....

Example, I delete application folder CVM ES_1_0_1_22 from my list of deployments (that run upto 24), i create new publisher, when this runs it creates the delete 1_22 folder and then creates then next folder as required....
[image]

How do I stop it from recreating the old application folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - think Ive found the answer.
When deploying with clickonce; on your local drive you end up with
bin\Release\net6.0-windows7.0\win-x64\app.publish\Application Files

If these are missing on the target deployment directory they get copied back across.